# give a predefined size to the profile images of users like whatsapp

Tags: android

I have an application in which users have the opportunity to upload images for their profile in the gallery.

To achieve this I save the path of the image in shared preferences and place the image uri in an imageView.

everything works fine but when users download images dimenssion variable imageView is not very pretty to see so I would like to give an image size to respect for the profile as whatsapp does so that all users have the same dimension for their profile image.

how can I implement this please?

Here is what I did for selecting an image in the gallery

```
Intent intent;
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            } else {
                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            }
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE);
```

And

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (data != null) {
                mImageUri = data.getData();

                SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                editor.putString("image", String.valueOf(mImageUri));
                editor.commit();

                imageView.setImageURI(mImageUri);
                imageView.invalidate();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend you to use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) or any [Avatar](https://github.com/search?q=android+avatar) component for Android.